# dart : handle api failures with the use of either

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i don't know what i am doing wrong or how to do it probably , in firebase it has been much easier with the `FirebaseAuthException` but here in a normal api i dont know how to handle my failures , like when it is `404` i want to display a specific error but i have reached a dead end because the IDE always tells me that `The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.` iam returning a failure ate the end so what's the problem ? and i want to handle every failure not only `socketexception` .
thank you !

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:mscmu/domain/i_api_request/failures/api.failures.dart';
import '../../../../domain/i_api_request/folders/contracts/i.folders.repository.dart';
import '../../../../domain/models/foldermodel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FolderRepository implements IFolderRepository {
  @override
  Future<Either<ApiFailures, List<FolderModel>>> mainFolders(int courseId) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php"),
      body: {"flag": "selectmainfolders", "course": "$courseId"}
    );
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var l = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
        var folders = l.map((e) => FolderModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
        return right(folders);
      } 
    } on SocketException catch(error) {
      return left(ApiFailures.badRequest());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an else statement:

```
class FolderRepository implements IFolderRepository {
  @override
  Future<Either<ApiFailures, List<FolderModel>>> mainFolders(int courseId) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php"),
      body: {"flag": "selectmainfolders", "course": "$courseId"}
    );
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        [...]
        return right(folders);
      } else { // 404, 500, ...
        [...]
        return ???;
      }
    } on SocketException catch(error) {
      return left(ApiFailures.badRequest());
    }
  }
}
```

If you use just a

```
if ([...]) {
  [...]
  return something;
}
```

or a

```
if ([...]) {
  [...]
  return something;
}
else if ([...]) {
  [...]
  return somethingElse;
}
```

Then, you are missing the else branch that will return `null` and cause your error.

Answer (score 0):

Your function must return something
that `socketexception` wont work on every error ... you should add return something when the `response.statusCode` is not 200

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var l = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      var folders = l.map((e) => FolderModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return right(folders);
}else{
   ////////return something
}
```

you got to return `Either<ApiFailures, List<FolderModel>>` as you have written in your function

Comment: Future<Either<ApiFailures, List<FolderModel>>> mainFolders(
      int courseId) async {
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("http://msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php"),
        body: json.encode({"flag": "selectmainfolders", "course": "$courseId"}));
  
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var l = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
      var folders = l.map((e) => FolderModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return right(folders);
    } else if(response.statusCode==404){
      return left(ApiFailures.badRequest());
    }

  
  }

won't work

Comment: i must catch it with some error handling but it won't work

Comment: @FahmiSawalha do not use else if ....  use else{} ... it wont it does not matter if your eror is 404 or 500 if it is not 200 you should act as error to that